# Best approach to cycle through background colors for collection cells in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In Swift, what would be the best approach to loop through background colors for cells in a collection view? I know I could do something like if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0), but putting the logic in an if clause seems clunky if there are going to be more than two color options.

My initial thought would be to put the list of colors in an array and loop through them. Is it possible to loop through an array in Swift within cellForItemAtIndexPath? Is there a better approach than looping through an array of background colors?

Comment: why should you loop and not just access colours array using indexPath.row as index, something like colorsArray[indexPath.row]?

Comment: @teamnorge Thanks! New to Swift and didn't even think of using indexPath.row. Makes much more sense. Will it raise an error if indexPath.row is greater than the number of colors in colorsArray?

Comment: @Oakland510 Yes, it will. However, you just have to do something like colorsArray[indexPath.row % colorsArray.count] ;)